# Why c# doesn't preserve the context for an anonymous delegate calls?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, c#-4.0, delegates

I have the following method:

```
static Random rr = new Random();
static void DoAction(Action a)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(par =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(rr.Next(200));
        a.Invoke();
    });
}
```

now I call this in a for loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var x = i;

    DoAction(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i); // scenario 1
        //Console.WriteLine(x); // scenario 2
    });
}
```

in scenario 1 the output is: `10 10 10 10 ... 10`
in scenario 2 the output is: `2 6 5 8 4 ... 0` (random permutation of 0 to 9)

How do you explain this? Is c# not supposed to preserve variables (here `i`) for the anonymous delegate call?

Comment: But preserving ('capturing') the *variable* `i` is *exactly* what's happening! What *isn't* happening, though you want it to, is preserving *the **value** of `i` at the time the delegate is set up*.

Comment: Incidentally, ReSharper will warn you about an [Access to modified closure](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/Access+to+modified+closure) when presented with this code; you might find the explanation there helpful.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here is that there is one `i` variable and ten instances / copies of `x`.  Each lambda gets a reference to the single variable `i` and one of the instances of `x`.  Every  `x` is only written to once and hence each lambda sees the one value which was written to the value it references.

The variable `i` is written to until it reaches 10.  None of the lambdas run until the loop completes so they all see the final value of `i` which is 10

I find this example is a bit clearer if you rewrite it as follows

```
int i = 0;  // Single i for every iteration of the loop
while (i < 10) { 
  int x = i;  // New x for every iteration of the loop 
  DoAction(() => {
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    Console.WriteLine(x);
  });
  i++;
};
```

Comment: More pointedly, every `x` is not just written to only once, but is a different `x` since it's initialised each time. There are 10 `x`'s in the lifetime of the loop and only one `i`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll get the same result with java or any Object oriented Language (not sure but here it seems logical).

The scope of `i` is for the whole loop and the scope of `x` is for each occurrence.

Resharper helps you top spot this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

`DoAction` spawns the thread, and returns right away. By the time the thread awakens from its random sleep, the loop will be finished, and the value of `i` will have advanced all the way to 10. The value of `x`, on the other hand, is captured and frozen *before* the call, so you will get all values from `0` to `9` in a random order, depending on how long each thread gets to sleep based on your random number generator.